# Is it possible to modify a variable of a grub module via /etc/default/grub or /etc/grub.d?

Tags: boot, grub2, themes

Grub sets the minimum number of displayed OS to 3, if 3 or more OS are present. See code below, which is found in module `gui_list.c`, which is a module of `gfxmenu.mod`.

```c
static void  
list_get_minimal_size (void *vself, unsigned *width, unsigned *height)  
{  
  list_impl_t self = vself;

  if (check_boxes (self))  
    {  
      int boxpad = self->item_padding;  
      int item_vspace = self->item_spacing;  
      int item_height = self->item_height;  
      int num_items = 3;
```

- I want to change the variable `num_items` to another integer.
- I would like to achieve something like: `GRUB_MIN_NUM_ITEMS= some integer`
- Editing `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d` is fine for a solution
- I don't want to recompile grub as a solution

This is also referenced at:

http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/Grub2_theme_tutorial#height.2C_item_height.2C_item_spacing_-_items_composition

Also note, that minimal number of shown items (N) - is 3.